# way to initialize a boolean array in c99

Tags: c, boolean, c99

What is the best way to initialize a boolean array in C99?

Maybe I can use this, I think.

```
bool f[5] = {false,};
```

Is this really okay?

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Initialize *to what*? What initial value? And define "best". Aside from string literals for `char` arrays, there only *one* way to explicitly initialize an array in C - by using a `{ ... }` initializer. There are no other ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to initialize your array to "all false"/"all zeros" initial value, you can do

```
 bool f[5] = { false };
```

or you can do

```
 bool f[5] = { 0 };
```

Which variant is "the best" is for you to decide. There's no definitively "best" way here. Each one is as good as the other.

Comment: It only works because zero equates to `false`, you could not use that method if you want to initialise all elements to `true`.

Comment: @cdarke You are right. There's no way to initialize all elements to `true` besides meticulously supplying an explicit `true` initializer for each array element.

Comment: Just to clarify: `bool f[5] = { false };` only initialises the first element; all other elements are "standard-initialised" according to C standard.

Comment: @Bugfinger: Well, it initializes *all* elements. You can say that it *explicitly* initializes only the first element (since that is where that `false` goes), while the rest are *implicitly* initialized (with `false` as well). But the end result is that all elements of the array are initialized with `false`. And no, there's no such thing as "standard-initialised" in C standard. According to C standard the remaining part of an aggregate is initialized by the same rules as static initialization (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10)

Comment: What I wanted to make clear is that it only initialises the fist element to the given value because it could be surprising. So `bool f[3] = { true };` results in { true, false, false }.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but still first result on google if you search for "initialize bool array" on Google. The answer the author accepted is plain wrong and works by luck, not design. This fact is worth mentioning as an answer itself.

Bugfinger pointed this out in the comments to the accepted answer.

You can try it yourself by declaring:
`bool             array[4] = { true}`
and check [1], [2] and [3] which are initialized to "0" (false) - which is correct and in the C99 standard. "All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are zero-initialized."

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization